# Č doesn't sort in bibliography correctly but {\v C} does

Tags: bibtex, unicode, sorting

I have an example here of an article document using pdflatex, bibtex, and natbib, where the Č character for Čermak isn't sorted in the bibliography correctly. I don't understand why not. Both files are encoded as utf-8 by my editor, and the pdf shows the character correctly. If instead I use {\v C} in the bib file, the sorting is correct (so obviously this is my current workaround, but I don't want to have to do it for all my refs if I don't have to).

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,final]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
See \cite{cermak_heat_1985,ingebritsen_sanford_1999}
\bibliographystyle{apalike} 
\bibliography{mwe} 
\end{document}
```

and the bib file:

```
@BOOK{ingebritsen_sanford_1999,
  title = {Groundwater in geologic processes},
  publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
  year = {1999},
  author = {Ingebritsen, S. E. and Sanford, Ward E.},
  pages = {341}
}
@ARTICLE{cermak_heat_1985,
  author = {Čermak, Vladimír and Jetel, Ján},
  title = {Heat flow and ground water movement in the {B}ohemian {C}retaceous {B}asin
    ({C}zechoslovakia)},
  journal = {Journal of Geodynamics},
  year = {1985},
  volume = {4},
  pages = {285--303},
  number = {1–4},
}
```

Comment: Ahh, my `.bib` files are full of `{\noopsort{ZZZ}}{\v Z}ivanovi{\'c}` ... a little trick which sorts `Ž` "correctly", i.e. not as `Z`. (`\noopsort` is of course defined as `\providecommand{\noopsort}[1]{}`.) I'm also switching bo biblatex/biber as soon as I have the time to go through my `.bib` files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`BibTeX` can not handle UTF8 characters, when it comes to sorting everything must be ASCII. So the `Č` is ignored in sorting. To deal with other characters, `BibTeX` has the rule that `{\command{C}}` is supposed to be a fancy accent, and should be sorted as C. Your options are thus to either switch to `biblatex`, or encode all author names with the "fancy accent" style:

```
author = {{\v{C}}ermak, Vladim{\'{\i}}r and Jetel, J{\'a}n}
```

See also the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/btxdoc.pdf) for the ugly details.

Comment: Ah, good one bibtex. Thanks @mafp for the quick answer! I hadn't heard of biblatex, but it looks the goods.

Comment: The problem is that `.bib` files are a useful resource to share (among colleages, have some common ones for the project, ...), and in that setting you'd better have ASCII-only files (no, BibLaTeX doesn't solve the character encoding problems, you need extra pieces like biber for that; and that one I could never get to even build).

Comment: Ahh this could be more trouble than it's worth. I have texlive 2009, so no biber pre-installed. I also needed to install biblatex from the Ubuntu repositories as a pre-requisite to biber.

biber versions are closely related to biblatex versions, and there are specific compatibilities - see any of the recent biber docs for the compatibility table. The Ubuntu 12.04 (precise) biblatex is v1.7x, so need biber v0.99. I got the binary from sf.net and put it in ~/bin.

Comment: There is a natbib package option for compatibility with natbib citation commands (\citep, \citet).