# biblatex sorting problem when the author's name starts with cedilla accent

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I ran into the following problem with **biblatex**. I use bibliography sorted by authors names, and one author's name starts with S-cedilla, which is encoded as `\c{S}`. This author then is placed as if their name started with C, not S. Is there a quick fix for that?

Comment: `{\c{S}}` or directly `Ş`

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99169/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for accented characters in BibTeX files is

```
{\c{S}}
```

but `biblatex`/Biber also accept UTF-8, provided the document is so encoded.

Here's an example.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{A,
  author={{\c{S}}author, X.},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  date={2014},
}
@article{B,
  author={Şuthor, X.},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  date={2014},
}
@article{C,
  author={Cauthor, X.},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  date={2014},
}
@article{D,
  author={Dauthor, X.},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  date={2014},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{A}, \cite{B}, \cite{C}, \cite{D}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]